# Building Python wheels in Docker for Raspberry Pi Zero on x86_64 machine

Tags: docker, python-wheel, armv6, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm hoping this is an appropriate venue for my question. There's a lot of pieces to this puzzle.

I'm building a container using Docker that is destined to run on a Raspberry Pi Zero. The RPi Zero has an ARMv6 hard-float processor. The container will run a Python program that includes some dependencies that must be compiled (uses binary libraries). I am able to build and run the container on the RPi Zero itself, but building the container literally takes hours. I'm hoping to 1) speed up the process of building and 2) allow this to happen in a CI environment.

The approach I've taken in the past to build minimal Python containers that have dependencies requiring compilation is to use a multistage Docker build. I first startup a container with a full toolchain, then run `pip wheel` to compile all requirements into .whl files. I then copy the .whl files to the final container, install any binary libraries using the typical package manager, and then point `pip install` at this cache (`--find-links=/wheels`) for the installation of Python dependencies. This approach also works just fine on the Pi, but as I said it takes forever.

I've considered a few different approaches I could take:

1. Figure out how to get the Docker engine on my main dev machine (also in CI) to run and build an ARM image using `qemu-arm-static` while running `docker build`, and then somehow tag the resulting image as ARMv6 and upload it to my registry somehow. (I could just use a tag or a different repo name) I haven't honestly dug too deep into this, but my main concern is that every example I've seen of `qemu-arm` seems to indicate that it runs ARMv***7*** emulation. The RPi Zero can't actually even run many Docker containers that are made available for ARM due to this (exit 139). The `arm32v6` "user" does provide working base images that run fine on the RPi Zero, which is what I'm using as the source images to build on my Pi itself.
2. Emulate an entire RasPi using `qemu-system-arm`. Again though, it looks like this emulates ARMv7, meaning the compiled wheels might not be able to run on the Pi zero.
3. Setup a cross-compiling toolchain for ARMv6. A few problems: I wouldn't know how to make sure `pip` uses that toolchain when compiling, and also I'd need to get and compile any other dependent library (even possibly all the way down to glibc?) so the header files will resolve.

It looks like this is easy to do if you want to do it for ARMv7 (which I believe the RPi 2 uses) or later, but I'm specifically using a Zero for my project, so I don't have that option.

TL;dr: How do I build binary Python wheels for ARMv6 using Docker without having to do it on a slow, single-core Raspberry Pi Zero?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I found some arm32v6 docker images but didn't try it yet